# How to read content from 'php://output' stream

Tags: php, php-stream-wrappers

According to the  docs **php://output** is only a writable stream, is there any way to read whatever was streamed to it as a content(possibilly a string);

```
$content = fopen('php://output',r);
```

tried above code but no use.

Comment: I mean, the obvious answer is that `php://output` is the output stream *for the current script*, so I would hope you already know what it contains. Can you add any more context?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot read from `php://output` From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

> php://output is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism in the same way as print and echo.

Comment: But the output buffer contents can be captured in the usual ways, so that hint from the manual there should be all that is needed ;-)